# Mapping source code to a new folder on a different drive in TFS

Tags: tfs

I have the source code currently mapped to

```
C:\Source
```

I would like to change this to a folder on D: drive as C: has very little space. After the mapping I will remove the one from the C: drive.

Can someone please point to a resource on how to go about this?
Using VS 2013.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on each project in the tree in source control, and select Advanced, you will see an item, "Remove Mapping."  This will remove your current mapping.  Then you can go back into the Advanced menu and select "Map to Local Folder," to map to your D drive. I'm not sure how this will work at the top level, but you could try it.

This process will remove the files from the previous map from your D drive.  If you want to delete them after the re-mapping, I suggest this chain:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ffa3aa15-1d61-4464-ac4a-7a812d073a67/remove-mapping